# How can I reserve memory for a very large sieve?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, limit

I want to generate primes by sieving up to 100,000,000 but declaring a bool array of this range is crashing my program.
This is my code:

```
long long i,j,n;
bool prime[100000000+1];
prime[1]=prime[0]=false;
for(i=2;i<=100000000;i++){
    prime[i]=true;
}
for(i=2;i<=100000000;i++){
    if(prime[i]==false){
        continue;
    }
    for(j=i*2;j<=100000000;j+=i){
        prime[j]=false;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is a limit to the stack size. Use `malloc`/`new` or `mmap` to reserve memory dynamically.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: If you want to use something like that in C/C++ you may want to use a specialized data structure to optimize the usage of your memory space i.e. make it use 1 bit not 1 byte

Comment: @StanR. no should be `C++` as there is bool type.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, you should let the OP tell us the language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables can be stored in three different memory areas: static memory, automatic memory, dynamic memory. Automatic memory (non-static local variables) has limited size, you crossed it, and this crashed the program. The alternative is to mark your array static, which will place your array in static storage, or use dynamic memory.

Since this is tagged C++...
Use `std::vector` which is simple to use and uses dynamic memory.

```
#include <vector>
//...
//...
long long i,j,n;
std::vector<bool> prime(100000000+1, true);
prime[1]=prime[0]=false;
for(i=2;i<=100000000;i++){
    if(prime[i]==false){
        continue;
    }
    for(j=i*2;j<=100000000;j+=i){
        prime[j]=false;
    }
}
```

`std::vector<bool>` uses "bit-efficient" representation, which means that std::vector here will take about eight<sup>1</sup> times less memory than traditional array.

`std::bitset` is similiar, but is constant in size, and you have to mark it static to avoid taking space in automatic memory.

You haven't asked, but Erastostenes Sieve is not the fastest algorithm for calculating a lot of prime numbers. It seems that [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) is faster and uses less memory.

<sup>1</sup> - When your system has 8-bit bytes.

Comment: **Why** should he change his code? You are missing the explanation

Answer (score 3):

The size of the array prime is 100 MB and declaring so big array on the stack is not allowed. Try placing the array in global scope to allocated it on the heap or alternatively allocate it using new(in `C++`) or malloc(in `C`). Don't forget to free the memory after that!

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* make a single monolithic sieve of that size. Instead, use a segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes to perform the sieving in successive segments. At the first segment, the smallest multiple of each sieving prime that is within the segment is calculated, then multiples of the sieving primes are marked composite in the normal way; when all the sieving primes have been used, the remaining unmarked number in the segment are prime. Then, for the next segment, the smallest multiple of each sieving prime is the multiple that ended the sieving in the prior segment, and so the sieving continues until finished.

Consider the example of sieving from 100 to 200 in segments of 20; the 5 sieving primes are 3, 5, 7, 11 and 13. In the first segment from 100 to 120, the bitarray has 10 slots, with slot 0 corresponding to 101, slot *k* corresponding to 100 + 2*k* + 1, and slot 9 corresponding to 119. The smallest multiple of 3 in the segment is 105, corresponding to slot 2; slots 2+3=5 and 5+3=8 are also multiples of 3. The smallest multiple of 5 is 105 at slot 2, and slot 2+5=7 is also a multiple of 5. The smallest multiple of 7 is 105 at slot 2, and slot 2+7=9 is also a multiple of 7. And so on.

Function `primes` takes arguments *lo*, *hi* and *delta*; *lo* and *hi* must be even, with *lo* < *hi*, and *lo* must be greater than the square root of *hi*. The segment size is twice *delta*. Array *ps* of length *m* contains the sieving primes less than the square root of *hi*, with 2 removed since even numbers are ignored, calculated by the normal Sieve of Eratosthenes. Array *qs* contains the offset into the *sieve* bitarray of the smallest multiple in the current segment of the corresponding sieving prime. After each segment, *lo* advances by twice *delta*, so the number corresponding to an index *i* of the *sieve* bitarray is *lo* + 2 *i* + 1.

```
function primes(lo, hi, delta)
  sieve := makeArray(0..delta-1)
  ps := tail(primes(sqrt(hi)))
  m := length(ps)
  qs := makeArray(0..m-1)
  for i from 0 to m-1
    qs[i] := (-1/2 * (lo + ps[i] + 1)) % ps[i]
  while lo < hi
    for i from 0 to delta-1
      sieve[i] := True
    for i from 0 to m-1
      for j from qs[i] to delta step ps[i]
        sieve[j] := False
      qs[i] := (qs[i] - delta) % ps[i]
    for i from 0 to delta-1
      t := lo + 2*i + 1
      if sieve[i] and t < hi
        output t
    lo := lo + 2*delta
```

For the sample given above, this is called as `primes(100, 200, 10)`. In the example given above, `qs` is initially [2,2,2,10,8], corresponding to smallest multiples 105, 105, 105, 121 and 117, and is reset for the second segment to [1,2,6,0,11], corresponding to smallest multiples 123, 125, 133, 121 and 143.

The value of *delta* is critical; you should make *delta* as large as possible so long at it fits in cache memory, for speed. Use your language's library for the bitarray, so that you only take a single bit for each sieve location. If you need a simple Sieve of Eratosthenes to calculate the sieving primes, this is my favorite:

```
function primes(n)
  sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
  for p from 2 to n step 1
    if sieve(p)
      output p
      for i from p * p to n step p
          sieve[i] := False
```

You can see more algorithms involving prime numbers at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/themes/#Prime%20Numbers).